# Scp via multiple intermediate host using ssh-key

Tags: scp

I have an scenario where I have to scp a file between A (Local M/C) to D, where B and C are jump boxes, but access to D from C requires a ssh key.

A -> B -> C -> D

Any pointers are much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the key for D stored on C? or where?

Answer (score 0):

You can use port forwarding to chain a set of SSH connections together establishing a connection from A to B with porftfowarding to C. Then subsequently you SSH from C to D with portforwarding to D. After that you can use scp on the exposed portforward to D.

```
ssh -L 1234:B:22 <user at A>@<address of A> 
ssh -L 1235:C:22 <user at B>@localhost -p 1234 
ssh -L 1236:D:22 <user at C>@localhost -p 1235
scp -P 1236  -i yoursshkey <user at D>@localhost /filetocopy /filedestination
```